# About uniform convergence.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis, uniform-convergence

Let $f$ and $f_1, f_2, \dots, f_n, \dots$ be continuous functions on $[a, b]$.
Suppose that $\lim_{n \to \infty} f_n(x) = f(x)$ for any $x \in [a, b]$.

I think the following proposition is true:

> If $\bigcap_{n = 1}^\infty \{x \in [a, b] ; f(x) = \max \{|f(x) - f_n(x)| ; x \in [a, b]\} \} \ne \emptyset$, then $\{f_n\}$ converges uniformly to $f$.

If $\bigcap_{n = 1}^\infty \{x \in [a, b] ; f(x) = \max \{|f(x) - f_n(x)| ; x \in [a, b]\} \} = \emptyset$, then is it possible that there exists $\{f_n\}$ which doesn't converge uniformly to $f$?

Comment: Take xⁿ on [0,1],,,as counter example

Comment: @Subhajit I assume that $f$ is continuous.

Comment: Take nx /(1+n²x²) on [0,1]

Comment: @Subhajit Thank you very much for your very nice example.

Answer (score 2):

As infinite intersection is not empty, this means exists $\exists  x_0 \in [a,b]$ (1), in which we have maximum for all functions i.e.$\forall n \in \mathbb{N}, \max \{|f(x) - f_n(x)| = |f(x_0) - f_n(x_0)|$ (2). As sequence $f_n$ is convergence in all points from $[a,b]$, then it also converges in $x_0$ i.e. $|f(x_0) - f_n(x_0)| \to 0$ (3). By limit definition it means,that $\forall \epsilon > 0$ existence of $N(x_0)$ , that for $\forall n > N(x_0)$ we have $|f(x_0) - f_n(x_0)| < \epsilon$. From our property this estimation holds for all $[a,b]$, which gives us uniform convergence.

Comment: is it implies for all x, I am little bit confusing!

Comment: Here a theorem, Mₙ= sup|fₙ - f|, lim Mₙ= 0 off fₙ is uniform to f,

Comment: Here according to @tchappy ha Mₙ is the max|fₙ - f|,

Comment: We find $N$ for $x_0$, but it's useful for all $[a,b]$ from brought estimation.

Comment: So if there some point where Mₙ coincides with f,,,,then at these f must be 0 for uniform convergence.

Comment: Added to answer some more details.

Comment: why don't you use the part f= max|fₙ - f|

Comment: If you don't use max equal f part,,,,your proof can be contradicted by 
fₙ=nx /(1+n²x²),,,fₙ is pointwise to 0,,,now for all n, max |fₙ-0| is 1/2,,,,now how do you use point wise limit convergence part,,

Comment: You use the point of intersection,,,ok,,,then can you explain me please,,,what is the speciality about point of intersection,,,where your proof can be applicable,,,, @zkutch please explain !!!

Comment: @Subhajit. Answers on all your questions are there, but, anyway, for your convenience I added numeration. Using max have number (2), point wise convergence number (3) and point intersection (1). But you shouldn't only remember that, but try to understand. Firstly study definitions, then find logic in answer. And do not worry so much, please. Here is not free math. exam emergency service - always will be somebody, who will try to help you, but in frames of h/is/er time and possibility. Leave your questions, be patient, please, and you'll get answers.

Comment: Firstly sorry,,If I show disrespect by any means. I just want to understand the logic that what's the importance of point of intersection and how should it use? Thanks

Comment: Thanks for understanding. point of intersection is used in sentence numbered (1). Do you want to move this discussion to private chat and continue?